# Pegar elemento "filho" de uma DIV

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho visto vários exemplos de como fazer isso aqui no stack, mas não sei por que as respostas nao esclarecem muito, **então gostaria** de perguntar de novo como eu poderia usar JS pra pegar o "ID da tag `<A>` da seguinte DIV, LEMBRANDO que meu codigo esta na DIV pricipal.

```
<li id="sem-importancia">
 <DIV id="principal">
   <a id="um-teste"> </a>
 </DIV>
</li>
```

quando eu uso o seguinte js, funciona perfeito e pego uma tag acima...

```
var item_id = elem.parent('li').attr('id');
```

LOGO que codigo usar para pegar a tag  abaixo  ? a

```
< a id="um-teste" > < /a >
```

obrigado!

Comment: Você está usando jQuery? Isso aqui não funciona em JavaScript: `elem.parent('li').attr('id');` Solução com jQuery é uma coisa, com JavaScript puro é outra. Vi uma resposta que vc aceitou anteriormente, sobre pegar ID de um elemento, que a resposta está errada se for JS puro (Se funcionou pra vc, é pq usou jQuery. Quando é assim, tem que por nas tags que é jQuery). Sugeriria corrigir aquela e essa aqui, se vc quiser em jQuery também. Se bem que pra essas coisas simples, o ideal é JS puro.

Comment: Se for em jQuery tem essa pergunta relacionada: pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/como-selecionar-os-elementos-irmãos

Comment: ola **Bacco** e **Gagriel**, bom ..como sou novato por favor me desculpem esses erros...  eu jurava que era soh JS...  Tenho percebido agora. que esse projeto que estou trabalhando.. tem partes de jquery e partes em JS...  estou tentando aprender...  tambem acho que o idela seja JS puro..  ou pelo menos ate eu aprender...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hierarquia de objetos, e estruturas `html`, `xml`, etc, seguem uma logica bem semelhante a de uma pessoa (Ou objeto qualquer). O componente tem um "pai", ou sejá, algum componente que deu origem a ele ou o componente a qual ele pertence, cada elemento só tem 1 pai.

Quando os elementos estão dentro de um elemento especifico, são chamados de elementos filhos, no caso um pai pode ter vários filhos, que é a logica para se colocar vários elementos dentro de um.

No `javascript` os elementos da tabela DOM tem o atributo `parentElement` responsável para recolher o elemento pai. Também possui os atributos dos elementos filhos que seriam:

childNodes - retorna uma NodeList dos elementos filhos.

childElementCount - retorna a quantidade de filhos que aquele elemento possui

children - retorna um vetor com os elementos filhos

Não entendi direito se vc queria uma explicação, ou o código para pegar os elementos, mais isso deve resolver.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('elem');

alert(el.parentElement.id);
alert(el.children[0].id);
```

```html
<ul id="pai">
  <li id="elem">
    <div id="filho">Item</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ola **Brumazzi** eu procurava "primeiro" pelo codigo, assim poderia esturar...... mas sua resposta foi uma verdadeira luz, **pra gente que ta comecando** .. e nem sabe fazer a pergunta direito...  nem sei como agradecer! 
quem me dera tivesse mais gente como voce (e alguns outros amigos que encontrei aqui) esclarecendo de maneira simples, OBJETIVA e com o exemplo do codigo...  repito.. "agente somos iniciantes..."  rsrsrs  BRIGADAO!

Comment: Ainda recebo muita ajuda e dicas no SO, como ainda faz pouco tempo que mecho com programação, ainda sei pouco, e constantemente aprendo muita coisa com as perguntas e respostar. "Programação é uma área vasta e sem fim", para sermos medianos, devemos nos esforçar dia apos dia. @RobervalSena山本

Comment: Cara, muito bom! Só para ajudar quem precisar, no meu caso eu usei isso: `document.getElementById('menu-topo').children[0].children[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i>';`. Note que `children[0]` aparece duas vezes.